# When I retrieve image from sql server 2008 r2 the image is black

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, image-processing, sql-server-2008-r2

I have write a program that on it i upload and download image to/from database `SQL Server 2008 R2` .
I upload image using code below :

```
SqlParameter picparameter = new SqlParameter();

            picparameter.SqlDbType = System.Data.SqlDbType.Image;

        picparameter.ParameterName = "value";

        picparameter.Value = val;//val is a byte array

        SqlCommand sqlcommand = new SqlCommand("update " + table + " set " + col + " = @value "+" where "+where, sqlconnection);
        sqlcommand.Parameters.Add(picparameter);
        sqlcommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

I convert image from an `PictureBox` to array using code below:

```
 public static byte[] ImageToByteArray(System.Drawing.Image img)
    {
        System.IO.MemoryStream ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
        Bitmap b = new Bitmap(img);
        b.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        return ms.ToArray();
    }
```

Then i download image from database to hard disk using code below :

```
Byte[] data = new Byte[0];
data = (Byte[])(imageReader["image"]);
MemoryStream mem = new MemoryStream(data);
Image.FromStream(mem).Save(Application.StartupPath + "\\Temp\\img\\" +imageReader["code"].ToString() + ".png",
System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
```

But, I have a big problem images back ground makes black after save them from database to hard disk.

[image: This is image that i upload it to data base]
[image: This is image that i download it from data base]

Comment: You're saving as jpeg but loading as png.  Was that intentional?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're saving as jpeg:

```
b.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

But loading as png:

```
Image.FromStream(mem).Save(..., ImageFormat.Png);
```

Not 100% sure that's your issue but it looks problematic.